# Using the SPARQL Query tab in Protoge to query elements within my own ontology

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege

I have an ontology that I am trying to qrite SPARQL queries for.

I'm using the Ontology IRI (http://www.semanticweb.org/chris/ontologies/2020/2/dis-coursework-ontology) displayed on the Active ontology tab to define the PREFIX value in the query below:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX chris: <http://www.semanticweb.org/chris/ontologies/2020/2/dis-coursework-ontology#>

SELECT ?class ?activity
    WHERE { ?class chris:hasActivity ?activity }
```

When I run this nothing is returned, yet when I output the ontology into RDF format I can see instances if what I want to be returned:

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/chris/ontologies/2020/2/dis-coursework-ontology#SportsHallBooking">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/chris/ontologies/2020/2/dis-coursework-ontology#BookableTimetable"/>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
                <owl:Restriction>
                        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/chris/ontologies/2020/2/dis-coursework-ontology#hasActivity"/>
                        <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/chris/ontologies/2020/2/dis-coursework-ontology#Badminton"/>
                </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
                <owl:Restriction>
                        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/chris/ontologies/2020/2/dis-coursework-ontology#hasActivity"/>
                        <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/chris/ontologies/2020/2/dis-coursework-ontology#Football"/>
                </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>
```

So I would expect the results to include:

> class | activity 
>  SportsHallBooking | Badminton 
>   SportsHallBooking | Football

Yet I get nothing back.

Comment: Like this: `select * { ?class rdfs:subClassOf [ owl:onProperty chris:hasActivity; owl:someValuesFrom ?activity ] }`

Comment: That was right if you want to add it as the answer I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Stanislav for the answer.

```
select * { ?class rdfs:subClassOf [ owl:onProperty chris:hasActivity; owl:someValuesFrom ?activity ] }
```